# How to calculate price based on weight

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I need guidance on the following if this is the scenario.

If Green Beans is configurable product with following Custom Options:

100g is of $10.75,
200g is of $21.50,
250g is of $32.25 and
500g is of $53.75.

And Qty may be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 up to 20.

So, Now if buyer buy 3 Qty of 500g then the calculation will be $53.75 x 3 = $161.25 and this amount should display on product detail page (when buyer select his/her requirement) and in cart page.

Now need guidance on How I can do this means, where I have setup the weight, qty,  price, formula and calculated figure for display.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom options ,make simple products for all Options and assign them to configurable product so it will automatically show price updates as per options(weight,quantity etc .. ) selected by customer .

hope this help you ..